# No existing transaction found for transaction marked with propagation 'mandatory' Exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-transactions

I am making a DB call from a method below:

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class, readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void addLogEntry(LogEntry logEntry) throws FatalException
{
    mNonTxAlarmService = CONTEXT.getBean(NonTxAlarmService.class);
    JobExecution jobExecution = mNonTxAlarmService.getJobExecution(mJobExecution.getId());

    logEntry.setJobExecution(jobExecution);
    jobExecution.getLogEntries().add(logEntry);
}
```

In which mNonTxAlarmService.getJobExecution() is a service call and it looks like below :

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true, propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY)
public JobExecution getJobExecution(Integer jobExecutionId)
    throws FatalException
{
    JobExecution jobExecution = mJobExecutionsService.get(jobExecutionId);
    return jobExecution;
}
```

And when it gets executed I get the below exception at line 
`JobExecution jobExecution = mNonTxAlarmService.getJobExecution(mJobExecution.getId());`:

```
org.springframework.transaction.IllegalTransactionStateException: No existing transaction found for transaction marked with propagation 'mandatory'
```

the main-dispatcher looks like this:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />   
<tx:annotation-driven /> 
...     
<bean> id="importModule" class="com.xxx.yyy.zzz.aaa.ImportModuleImpl"></bean>
```

addLogEntry is a method in ImportModuleImpl class.

Where am I getting it wrong ?

Comment: By not having a `<tx:annotation-driven />` or `@EnableTransactionManagement` in your configuration. Or you are scanning for the same components twice leading to 2 instances of which one is transactional and the other isn't.

Comment: I have `<tx:annotation-driven />' in my dispatcher servlet, but I don't completely understand what do you mean by "scanning for the same components twice"?

Comment: If you have a `ContextLoaderListener` and `DispatcherServlet` and each load an xml file which has the same `<context:component-scan />` they are detecting the same beans twice (duplicating all bean instances). Also if you have `<tx:annotation-driven />` in your `DispatcherServlet` and your beans are in the `ContextLoaderListener` it isn't going to do much as it has to be defined in the same context as the beans it has to make transactional...

Comment: No we use `DispatcherServlet` and I have also added the `main-dispatcherServlet` for reference, ant other thing that we might be missing ?

Comment: Are you really sure you are using that instance? Do you have a `ContextLoaderListener`? How is the `addLogEntry` method called?

Comment: I have this entry `<listener><listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class> </listener> ` in my web.xml  and the `addLogEntry()` is called from `@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class, readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW) private void retrieveAlarms() throws AMAFatalException, DCSException {}`

Comment: Please don't add code, xml , stacks as comments, but as improvements to your question. Regardless that is never going to work, spring uses proxies to apply AOP which means only external method calls are intercepted not internal method calls. `@Transactional` only has meaning on public methods when using Spring for AOP. So putting it on a private method isn't doing anything.

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful information, but I still get the same exception.

Comment: As stated make sure you are using the instance you think you are using, `@Transactional` on a private method isn't doing anything nor will transactions get started for internal method calls.

Comment: I changed the access of the method to public, one more bit of information, I have this piece of code runnign as a new thread, do I need to define `@Transactional` for the `run()` method also ?

Comment: So on a general level I want to understand when should a transaction begin, at what level ?

Comment: If you are running this as a new thread it probably is also a new instance you created yourself? Spring will only advice beans it knows about. The fact that you made it public doesn't mean it will now automatically have a transaction, if it still is an internal method call (from your `run` method for instance) it will still not work. Also you shouldn't be really starting threads yourself, use Springs task abstraction for that.

Comment: Your code is also a bit weird why aren't you using dependency injection? Why are you doing a lookup you should use dependency injection for that.

Comment: I could not use injection because we create a instance of this class in the code using reflection.

Comment: okay so it worked, but now I am trying to figure out how, in the stack call there was a method which was `protected`, I changed it to `public` and also gave the run call `@Transactional`. Still trying to figure out what worked.

Comment: And that is why it isn't working, you shouldn't be creating instances yourself (as I mentioned). Spring will only proxy bean instances it knows you are creating new ones yourself.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks a lot for your support, once I find out what worked I will post it here.